# Windows store. Submit app update to store but wait to release after approval

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

We have an updated version of our app which is distributed via the windows store to upload soon. I'd like to be able to submit it to the store, and have it go through the approval process but then not be immediately available for download until our clients have been brought up to speed and given documentation.
This way once the documentation / client stuff is done I could just hit a button to put it into release, rather than submit it then and wait X days for it to be approved.
Is this possible? I dont see any option in the windows dev centre, or any mention in the documentation, they are both pretty scanty imo.

Comment: I suggest contacting WIndows Dev support, or even a forum. This question is not directly related to programming, as you are simply submitting data to Windows and waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option exists in the new DevCenter for Windows 10 Apps (Dev.windows.com). Check Submissions-->Pricing & Availability --> Publish Date.
Select "Publish this app manually". Also see screenshot.

[image: Dev Center Screenshot]